# Loops make Less to run out of memory. (Structure optimization)

Tags: css, less, brunch

I'm working on a less project, but as is start to become a bit big, every time that i'm trying to compile  i run out of memory.

This is my current structure:

> - style.less
> - colors.less
> - icons.less
> - styles
>
>   - style1
>   - style2
>   - style3

Now,

> - colors.less is a list of colors and their classes
> - icons.less a list of icons and their classes
> - style.less is the main file, where all is included and compiled
> - styles is a folder containing all the difference for every different style

my question (well, actually is more a suggestion than a question) is:

> how can i optimize this structure so that i don't run out of memory
>   anymore when trying to compile?

The process is the following:

`colors.less` and `icons.less` contains my arrays with color, icons and classes, nothing more.

I have both `colors.less` and `icons.less` included into `style1.less`,`style2.less`,`style3.less`, where i create a loop trough the colors.

Finally, i'll import everything into style.less (the main one) where i create a loop trough the icons and then add all the  `MIXINS` to create the final result. the problem is that i can't compile as i run out of memory.

I'm pretty sure that there's something wrong on my structure or any way i can increase the memory (i'm compile using brunch -> [this link for official website](http://brunch.io/))

Any suggestion are really really appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

PS: for more information, just ask.

Comment: It's barely possible to suggest anything w/o knowing what exactly you're trying to compile... How can we know if it's really something big to fail to compile within your environment or it's just simply some infinite loop?

Comment: can you suggest a place where i can actually upload my files and then share a link so that they are available for you to check?

Comment: [GitHub](https://github.com/)?

Comment: https://github.com/nickimola/test here you are

Comment: Hmm, indeed it seems like it's just too big. Well, honestly I can't suggest anything specific that could help apart from removing [unused vars](https://github.com/nickimola/test/blob/master/app/less/style.less#L17) and moving duplicated properties into separate classes (e.g. like FontAwesome does). Two generic ideas though: first, you could try to compile each styles separately and then concatenate resulting CSS. Second: there's way to get rid of loops at all (obviously it's the loops who eat memory because of recursion), see for example  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25877100 (the last snippet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partial answer, there's way to get rid of loops: color and icon data can be defined as mixins calls, here's mini example:

```
.colors() {
    // "array" of colors
    .-(Maroon, #800000);
    .-(Red,    #FF0000);
    .-(Orange, #FFA500);
    .-(Yellow, #FFFF00);
}

// generate color classes:

.some-prefix {
    .colors();
    .-(@name, @color) {
        &.@{name} {
            color: contrast(@color);
            background: @color;
            // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Same for icons...