# Dynamic import in loop when using less

Tags: css, less

theme.less:

```
@theme: blue, red;
.createTheme(@i:1) when (@i <= length(@theme)) {
  @name: extract(@theme, @i);
  @import "@{name}.less";
  .@{name} {
    background: @footer-bg;
}
.createTheme()
```

blue.less:

```
@footer-bg:blue;
```

red.less:

```
@footer-bg:red;
```

I got error:

```
Module build failed: Recursive variable definition for @i
 @ D:\app\theme.less (line 10, column 0)
 near lines:

   .createTheme();
```

Any solution to fix that?

Comment: @import is a "static" construction (for multiple reasons), i.e. when you put it into a mixin, the import is resolved not when you call the mixin but when compiler reads the mixin definition, i.e. it's equal to just defining a mixin with the contents of the imported file (thus the interpolated variable may not be or depend on a mixin parameter). As for "multitheme" approach, there're a lot of methods to achieve the same w/o spoling the import interpolation. For example using [namespaces](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/5a43eb0e3eab34bc737963ddf93f487c).

Comment: For other multitheming patterns see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875846 (and other topics linked there). For the general weirdness of abusing the interpolated imports feature see [#2772](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2772), [#2442](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2442).

Comment: There are too many styles to be defined in the theme, and also there are almost 20+ themes, the solution you mentioned will cause too many codes.

Comment: *"the solution you mentioned will cause too many codes."*

You did not read all, did you? Because (one of) `namespace`-based solutions can be reduced to almost no additional code at all (if the compactness *is* the main goal, though usually it has negative effects on other aspects).